# Ошибка интеграции сайта на Tilda с системой 1с

Tags: 1с, tilda, commerceml

Проблема интеграция системы 1С с сайтом на платформе tilda .
После проведения  интеграции на страницу  сайта выгрузился каталог из системы 1С , но заказы сделанные на сайте не переходят в систему 1с

```
---начало---
Произошла ошибка: . По причине: 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<РљРѕРјРјРµСЂС‡РµСЃРєР°СЏРРЅС„РѕСЂРјР°С†РёСЏ Р’РµСЂСЃРёСЏРЎС…РµРјС‹="2.04" Р”Р°С‚Р°Р¤РѕСЂРјРёСЂРѕРІР°РЅРёСЏ="2021-03-15T11:17:07">
</РљРѕРјРјРµСЂС‡РµСЃРєР°СЏРРЅС„РѕСЂРјР°С†РёСЏ>

Не удалось разобрать данные, загруженные с сервера.
Обмен не выполнен
Не выгружен ни один заказ.
Обмен заказами завершен с ошибками!!!
---конец---
```